# Qt 5.5.1 mysql driver not loaded in ubuntu 32 bit 16.04

Tags: qt, qtsql

Qt mysql driver not loading in ubuntu 32 bit

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
qmysql check QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

added `libqsqlmysql.so` in Build Path and sqldrivers also .
but not working. 
qt creater 3.5.1(opensource). qt 5.5.1

```
QT       += core gui sql
```

Comment: Did you provide the libmysqlclient library? Did you rebuild your sql-driver for your libmysqlclient library? If not, install the devel package for mysql and rebuild the Qt mysql plugin

Comment: how to rebuild sql-driver

Comment: Mr.@Sebastian Lange am set `libqsqlmysql.so `   but where can i find `libmysqlclient' . how to identify it correct version

Comment: The libqsqlmysql.so is the library you want to rebuild. The other is part of the mysql server/mysql devel package. For the build instructions under linux pleas refer to google